# Highlighting result source in BeautifulSoup4 soupselect

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

this is my code:

```
import bs4
from soupselect import select

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<body><p>text</p></body>')
res = select(soup,'p')
```

I wold like to have something like this

```
print res[0].getsource()
```

### that will print as flow:

```
>>> 6,11
```

the offset of the element at the source text and is length

Comment: How did you come up with the number of 5 for the offset? You are not including the brackets apparently? And you know that BeautifulSoup will add more tags to your HTML-string?

Comment: My mistake the offset is 6.

Answer (score 2):

What you want cannot be done with either `soupselect` or BeautifulSoup; the Soup tree doesn't track original source offsets; the HTML parsers don't pass this information on when the tree is built.

Moreover, the tree builders *repair* broken HTML; the `html5lib` parser will insert missing HTML elements where required, like the `<html>`,`<head>`, `<body>` and `<tbody>` elements.

You should not use the `soupselect` project with BeautifulSoup 4; it was designed for version 3. Instead, use the [built-in `Element.select()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) for CSS selecting elements.

Answer (score 2):

I understand what you're after, but like Martijn Pieters said, it is not something that BeautifulSoup keeps track of.

That being said, you *can* do this with standard python functionality, but only given some constraints: the tags you're looking for should be unique (or you should add an offset in the `find` method of the string objects. Moreover, you should take into account that broken HTML will get repaired as good as possible, so if the original HTML was broken, don't expect a good match.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<body><p>text</p></body>')
>>> print(repr(soup))  # remark that new tags have been added!
<html><body><p>text</p></body></html>
>>> first_p = repr(soup.find('p'))  # it is now a string, no longer a tag
>>> repr(soup).find(first_p) # This will give the result, taking into account the newly added tags
12
>>> repr(soup).find(first_p) -6 # because the "<html>" tag was added automatically
6
>>> len(first_p)
11
```

But this does pose a good amount of constraints on the tags you're looking for. It should give you a start though.

Comment: I'm looking for a method that can extract the source of regular site html in a specific jquery selection